# Remember Me with Spring Security 3.1.3 - deprecated default constructors

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-security, deprecated

I'm doing a login with Spring Security 3.1 but I get a warning to deprecated and I could not get erased, it seems that this configuration is for version 3.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <form-login login-page="/pages/login.jsf"/>
        <remember-me key="jsfspring-sec" services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>
        <logout
            invalidate-session="true"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE"
            logout-success-url="/pages/login.jsf"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <user authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" name="admin" password="admin" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:property  name="key" value="jsfspring-sec" />
        <beans:property  name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <beans:property  name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
        <beans:property  name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="60" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="key" value="jsfspring-sec"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

I could not find how to do it with Spring 3.1. Can someone help me? The last three beans are deprecated, I would appreciate help. Here is the url of the repository in GitHub: https://github.com/wmanriques/spring_template

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site. Please don't post in other languages.

Comment: Could you please tell us which element is marked deprecated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default constructors are deprecated as Spring Security has moved to constructor injection in several classes lately.

```
/**
* @deprecated Use constructor injection
*/
```

Now required components need to be injected with `constructor-arg`:

```
<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    //First two with constructor - required elements
    <beans:constructor-arg value="jsfspring-sec"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="userDetailsService"/>

    //Last two with properties
    <beans:property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="60" />
</beans:bean>
```

Same with next 2 beans:

```
<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="jsfspring-sec"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="rememberMeServices"/>
</beans:bean>
```